# How do I display the CFBundleShortVersionString in my LaunchStoryboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Is there any way to display the CFBundleShortVersionString as a UILabel text in my LaunchStoryboard without entering it by hand every time it increments? I know how to do it in code, but it is not possible to run code while the LaunchStoryboard is shown.
Is it possible through Xcode variables?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. It now has a complete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the script to update the Version & Build label on LaunchScreen.storyboard based on the first answer without using any extra files. Unfortunately, Clemens Brockschmidt's solution doesn't work due to some Syntax errors and incorrect paths.

Make sure to name your label to "APP_VERSION" in Identity Inspector pane -> Document -> Label.

Also create your script before "Copy Bundle Resources" phase.

**UPDATE:** My older answer didn't work in the newest Xcode environment. I've fixed the current issues and refactored the script.

And here's the final working script with shell: /bin/sh in **XCode 11 (Swift 5)**:

```
#   ON/OFF Script Toggle (script ON with #, script OFF without #)
#exit 0

#   Increment Build Number Bool (Increment ON with true, increment OFF with false)
shouldIncrement=false

#   App vesion / Build version constants
sourceFilePath="$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard"
versionNumber="$MARKETING_VERSION"
buildNumber="$CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION"


#   Increment build number
if [ "$shouldIncrement" = true ]; then
    buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
fi

#   Output version & build numbers into a label on LaunchScreen.storyboard
sed -i .bak -e "/userLabel=\"APP_VERSION\"/s/text=\"[^\"]*\"/text=\"$versionNumber($buildNumber)\"/" "$sourceFilePath"
```

As a **BONUS** I've included a build number incrementer and ON/OFF script toggle to disable your incrementer when you build your project a lot. Let me know if you have any issues or if this works for you.

Answer (score 5):

As we all know, you can't put code in a launch screen. And unfortunately there isn't a built-in way to use a variable for a label's text in the launch screen (similar to how you can preprocess Info.plist with values in a header file).

The only option available to achieve your goal would be to write your own script that updates the LaunchScreen.storyboard file and add that script as a custom Build Phase for your target.

To make this easier, I would setup your target to use a preprocessor file for Info.plist. Once that is done and working, you now have a separate and simple header file you can interrogate in your script to process the LaunchScreen.storyboard file.

Here's a complete solution:

Create a file named `Info.h` and add it to the root of your project.

Add the following line:

```
#define APP_VERSION 2.6 // Update this version as needed
```

Now select your project's target in Xcode and go to the General tab. Change the Version value from whatever number you have there to `APP_VERSION`.

Now select the Build Settings tab. Search on `Info`. Under the Packaging section, set the `Preprocess Info.plist File` to `Yes`. Also set the `Info.plist preprocessing Prefix File` to `Info.h`.

Now when you do a build, the `CFBundleShortVersionString` value in Info.plist will be set to the value in the Info.h file.

To get the label in the launch screen file updated to match, do the following:

Select your launch screen storyboard and then select the label that will contain the version number. Show the Identity Inspector pane. Enter `APP_VERSION` into the Label attribute. If you look at the storyboard file now, the XML for the label will now show a `userLabel` attribute with the value of `APP_VERSION`.

Go back to the project target and select the Build Phases tab. Click the + icon and choose to add a New Run Script Phase. Rename the new phase to something useful like "Update Launch Version". Then drag the new phase to before the existing "Copy Bundle Resources" phase.

Now open the new "Update Launch Version" phase. Enter `/bin/bash` in the Shell field. Copy and paste the following code into the phase:

```
VERSION=`cat Info.h | grep APP_VERSION | cut -f3 -d' '`

sed -e "/userLabel=\"APP_VERSION\"/s/text=\"[^\"]*\"/text=\"$VERSION\"/" Storyboard.storyboard > tmp.storyboard
```

Now do a clean build. This is a test at this point. Have a look at `tmp.storyboard` and make sure it looks correct and the label for the app version is showing the proper version.

Once that is working, update the above code to:

```
VERSION=`cat Info.h | grep APP_VERSION | cut -f3 -d' '`

sed -i bak -e "/userLabel=\"APP_VERSION\"/s/text=\"[^\"]*\"/text=\"$VERSION\"/" Storyboard.storyboard
```

This final version actually updates the launch screen storyboard file. The previous version was a test to make sure everything else was working without risk to trashing your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me to get on the right track: Instead of using an `Info.h` file to set the version number, I read it directly from my `Info.plist`. Here is my complete script, no additional files required: `BUNDLE_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" "Info.plist")
sed -i bak -e "/userLabel=\"APP_VERSION\"/s/text=\"[^\"]*\"/text=\"$BUNDLE_ID\"/" LaunchScreen.storyboard`

Answer (score -1):

Edit

> There is no way to make the launch screen dynamic. Doesn't work good
>   with localizations too etc

A alternative is given below

> Previous Answer

You should make your inital VC similar to the LaunchScreen.xib and in that make a label.

Now in the ViewController you can access the info plist through NSBundle method and set its value. This would make the transition from Launch screen to first VC smooth and look natural with version code animating in or something if you want

```
let appVersion = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["CFBundleVersion"];
 myLabel.text = "\(appVersion)"
```

Comment: How does this show the version in the launch screen? You can't have code in a launch screen storyboard.

Comment: from the question i can see the requirement is to have the initial screen show the number without have to enter everytime, this will make it automatic and transition from launch screen to the version screen will still look natural

Comment: The OP wants the version to appear on the launch screen. Not some screen shown after the launch screen.

Comment: It has been edited later that he knows how to do by code. If he did not knew that. this would have been a good solution.

Comment: No, the edited question is to clarify that he is not looking for a code solution because someone voted to close this for the wrong reason and the only answer so far is offering a code solution. Since that isn't what they want, they updated the question to clarify that. Read the 1st sentence of the question. It asks how to show the version on the LaunchStoryboard.

Comment: A alternative to a requirement is still considered a solution. I dont see the point of arguing. Its meant to help the user. he has not specified in advance that i am not open to alternative of this question. Its like user asked in javascript, so you cant answer in Jquery. when indeed both are JS!

Comment: @Shubhank: I don't think rmaddy is arguing, just explaining that your answer isn't relevant to the question now that it's been clarified. You're solution is appropriate for the question that was originally thought to be a dupe I'd imagine, but no sense in beating a dead horse.