# Can Xamarin Ios storyboard file get App version from Info.plist?

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, info.plist

I want to show app version at splash screen.

I Searched how can get version from Info.plist and found this.

Ojbect-C

```
NSString *version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

swift

```
let version: String! = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as String
```

I thought storyboard file maybe wrote by object-c or swift.

But it was xml...

I have no idea how can i do this.

I found this

[How do I display the CFBundleShortVersionString in my LaunchStoryboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214139/how-do-i-display-the-cfbundleshortversionstring-in-my-launchstoryboard)

But sorry..I couldn't understand.

No more simple solution? If it impossible, I will have to change Info.plist and storyboard file every time update application.

I did with android this simply, Just made SplashActivity.cs file include a Label. Then add text like this.

```
FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblAppVersion).Text = $"Version {PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(PackageName, 0).VersionName}";
```

If you know solution, please teach me. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, you add a new screen to android and use it as your splash. If you do the same with iOS (make new ViewController) that will appear right after splash for a few seconds, you could put any label on it as well. If you want iOS to show it on splash, please, pay attention to link that you provide. It's actually not so hard to implement, and you would know much more after you did that.